# What is$\displaystyle \lim_{\substack{x \rightarrow 0^{+} \\ y \rightarrow 1^{-}}} \frac{x+y-1}{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{1-y}}$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Will be the value in the form of $\frac{"0"}{"0"}$? Do I have to use the L'Hopital rule? Or can I say, that the limit doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rationalize the denominator 
$$\lim_{\substack{x \rightarrow 0^{+} \\ y \rightarrow 1^{-}}} \frac{x+y-1}{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{1-y}} \frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{1-y}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{1-y}} = \\ 
\lim_{\substack{x \rightarrow 0^{+} \\ y \rightarrow 1^{-}}} \frac{(x+y-1)(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{1-y})}{x-(1-y)} = \\
\lim_{\substack{x \rightarrow 0^{+} \\ y \rightarrow 1^{-}}} \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{1-y} = 0$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: for $x \gt 0, y \lt 1\,$:

$$\require{cancel}
\frac{x+y-1}{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{1-y}} = \frac{x-(1-y)}{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{1-y}} = \frac{(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{1-y})\cancel{(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{1-y})}}{\cancel{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{1-y}}}
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One may observe that, as $x \to 0^+$, $y\to 1^-$,
$$
x+y-1=x-(1-y)=\left(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{1-y}\right)\left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{1-y}\right).
$$